# UI firebase separate to chat room, i want to go to home page first before the chatroom

Tags: android, firebase, chat, firebase-authentication

Can someone help me to have homepage first before it goes to chatroom? Here is my code. I don't know how could I edit that. I am using firebase ui / firebase auth. All I want is SIGN UP>SIGN IN>HOME>inside home it has image button of chat and then>CHAT

//mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private FirebaseListAdapter<Messagemodel>adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .build(),
                    SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE
            );
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Hello " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                            .getCurrentUser()
                            .getDisplayName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            displayMessages();
        }

        FloatingActionButton fab =
                (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference()
                        .push()
                        .setValue(new Messagemodel(input.getText().toString(),
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                                        .getCurrentUser()
                                        .getDisplayName())
                        );
                input.setText("");
            }
        });

    }

    public void displayMessages(){
        ListView listOfMessages = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);

        FirebaseListAdapter<Messagemodel> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Messagemodel>(this, Messagemodel.class,
                R.layout.message, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, Messagemodel model, int position) {
                TextView messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
                TextView messageUser = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                TextView messageTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

                messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
                messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
                messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                        model.getMessageTime()));
            }
        };

        listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Success!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                displayMessages();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Please try again later.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                finish();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_sign_out) {
            AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "signed out.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

But in that case when I already sign in/up the first will show was the chat room.

Comment: Create a homepage activity and transition (button press) to the chat activity?

Comment: @jeffreyhaines , yes it is.